# Kernel: Dealing with deadlocks in unix

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, deadlock

> A **deadlock** would occur if process 1 locks **resource A** and waits for
>   **resource B**, while simultaneously (due to context switches at the "right" places) process 2 locks **resource B** and waits for access to **resource 
>   A**.

How does Unix deal with such deadlocks? I read the following **[here](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/avoid-race.html)**.

> Many deadlocks can be prevented by simply requiring all processes that
>   lock multiple resources to lock them in the same order (e.g.,
>   alphabetically by lock name)

How can it **change the order** in which locks are acquired without also changing the execution order? 
Could someone **detail** the approach to deadlock-handling taken by the modern Unix kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linux kernel, it does NOT handle this, because it has no idea on how to fix it. Instead, it detects this kind of deadlock at runtime and complains.

The technology it uses is lockdep, which is a runtime locking correctness validator, for details, please take a look at kernel document [Documentation/lockdep-design.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/lockdep-design.txt).

Answer (score 2):

No, the order can't be changed by the OS. The phrase should be read as: "if the programmer is sensible and locks resources in the same order across all competing entities, many deadlocks will be impossible".

Comment: That makes more sense, but there are cases in which the locking **cannot** be done in the same order, and there exists the possibility of such a deadlock. In such cases, how does the kernel deal with the deadlock?

Comment: @Cthulhu As far as I know modern Unix kernels (Linux & BSD) don't really deal with deadlocks. I may be wrong though

Comment: Solaris does not alter or prevent deadlocks in userland code. dtrace tools (Gregg and Mauro) can show the state of objects like semaphores and mutexes. The logical meaning of the state of those objects is up to the programmer not the OS.

Comment: Couldn't a deadlock of this kind be intermittent as well, because if certain context switches at certain times. If that is true, it would be really hard to resolve deadlocks