# How does windows and linux kernel handle deadlock conditions?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

Assume a situation where the Linux kernel runs into a kernel thread deadlock condition, how does it handles it: Will it just stop kill the thread ,if yes, how does the kernel knows that this will not cause a kernel panic?

Is there any major difference on how the windows kernel handles such a condition?

P.S. I would be more than greateful for answers with code(coppied from kernel)-pseudocode.

Comment: The Linux kernel should never encounter such a condition because it requires that people take locks in a certain order.  Bugs do occasionally happen, though.

Comment: In a case that this occurs though how will it handle it ? @bk2204

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel: Dealing with deadlocks in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658645/kernel-dealing-with-deadlocks-in-unix)